# How can i give space from grids

Tags: grid

when i try to display blocks in grid then there is space at the end of grid item on right side and there is no space at the start of the grid i.e at the left side . You can see screenshot and code. i cannot figure it out what is the problem. I hope you can figure it out.[image]

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Projects</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <style>
         *{
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             box-sizing: border-box; 
          }
        .gird-section{
             display: grid;
             grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
             gap: 10px;
             margin-top: 40px;
             background-color: yellow;    
         }
        .grid-item{
             background-color: red;
             width: 500px;
             height: 100px;

          }

       </style>
     </head>
<body>
 
    <h1>Grid</h1>
    <div class="gird-section">

        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Css Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

I have edited your code so you can have yellow space left and right. I added width in the first section in order for the parent to have more with then the child . For more editing I suggest to watch the link above.

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Projects</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
 <style>
   * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   #grid {
     display: grid;
     height: 100px;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
   }

   #item1 {
     background-color: yellow;
     grid-column: 1/2;
   }

   #item2 {
     background-color: red;
     grid-column: 2/4;
   }

   #item3 {
     background-color: yellow;
     grid-column: 4/5;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Grid</h1>
 <div id="grid">
   <div id="item1"></div>
   <div id="item2"></div>
   <div id="item3"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks its work but there must be a gap between two column also,.

Comment: @Kamal check the code again. Should be with a gap now.